# How to set a block for dynamic node in DRUPAL 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-blocks

I am new to Drupal. I have created a block that I want to show on some specific pages. Like if the url is "/node/2278" then I want to show the block for all the page under this "/node/2278". This may be /node/2278/1 or /node/2278/any-number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "/node/2278/*" , I think it actually tells you that the star can be a wildcard under the textfield where you enter it.
Don't forget you can set up url aliases so the path does not have to be "node/..." but can be whatever you want (admin/config/search/path/patterns)

Comment: How can i use aliases here? cause node/2278 is static url but the rest url changes dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Followings Path configurations

using  (`node/2278`)  -> the block will display only on node/2278.

using  (`node/2278/*`) -> the block will display on node/2278/12 where ***** can be any text or number

using  (`node/2278/*/*`) -> the block will display only on node/2278/12/45 where ***** can be any text or number